# PB - Undocumented column.compute property

Tags: powerbuilder, datawindow

When you try dw_1.describe(column_name.attributes), you will see ...,color,coltype,**compute**,criteria.dialog,...

This means that **DW object of type Column** has undocumented **property compute**, this property isn't in Powerbuilder Help, isn't in datawindow painter, it is only listed in column.attributes.

Value of dw_1.object.column_name.compute is "?" and propably isn't setable via modify.

I tried "computed column", this mean SELECT col1+col2 as colA ..., to see if the property colA.compute would accidentally contain a "col1+col2", but not.

**Does anybody know, for what the undocumented property is?**

Maybe it is deprecated (or TODO) property.

Comment: I do not understand what you want. Please provide more information or at least a minimal working example.

Comment: I rewrote my question, I hope you understand it now.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I do not understand, here is the description of the property according to the PowerBuilder documentation:

**Attributes DataWindow object property**

**Description:** 
A tab-separated list of all the properties that apply to a control.

**Controls:** 
DataWindow, Button, Column, Computed Field, Graph, GroupBox, Line, OLE, Oval, Picture, Rectangle, Report, RoundRectangle, TableBlob, and Text controls

**Syntax** 
  PowerBuilder dot notation:
   dw_control.Object.controlname.Attributes

**Describe** argument:
    "controlname.Attributes"

Comment: Column has property compute, this property isn't in Powerbuilder Help, isn't in datawindow painter, it is only listed in column.attributes. Value of dw_1.object.columnname.compute is "?" and propably isn't setable via modify.

Comment: I tried "computed column", this mean SELECT col1+col2 as colA ..., to see if the property colA.compute would accidentally contain a "col1+col2", but not.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is deprecated (or TODO) property.

Answer (score 0):

Probably just a bug in the attribute property.